# Play 100 tickets in one lottery draw or 100 plays/draws with 1 ticket - same chances to win?

Tags: lotteries

5/49 lottery is when 5 different numbers are selected (without replacement) out of 49 possible numbers in range 1..49.

Total number of possible combinations is C(49, 5).

(1) If I make a stake once (on 5 numbers) - my chances are 1 / C(49, 5) - is over 1:10 million. If I make 100 stakes on 1 draw - I have `100/C(49,5)` chances.

(2) If I make 1 stake for 100 next draws, I have 100 events and use Bernoulli's formula `(C(n,k)*p^k*(1-p)^(n-k))` to get probability of k=1 events, each with probability p = 1/C(49,5) for n=100 trials.

(1) and (2) give the same result!

Is everything correct in my reasoning?

Comment: Yes, provided the 100 tickets in the first case are all on different sets of 5 numbers.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122053/is-it-better-to-play-1-on-10-lottery-draws-or-10-on-one-lottery-draw?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better to play $\$1$ on $10$ lottery draws or $\$10$ on one lottery draw?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122053/is-it-better-to-play-1-on-10-lottery-draws-or-10-on-one-lottery-draw)